# As with basic zoom controls kinect for windows v1.8

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox, kinect-interaction

How I can add zoom functionality to the basic controls kinect ie the Microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls?

Comment: What is your question? 
Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What kind of zoom are you implementing? Is it like Google Earth zooming ... zoom if both hands apart?